# How do I set a key binding for cmd + Q on Mac OSX?

Tags: league-of-legends, macos

I'm playing League of Legends on Mac OSX Mavericks.

For self-casting, rather than <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, I'd like <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.

So I go to key bindings and try to set it. But when it asks me to type the key combination, I can't, because this is OS X' shortcut for closing the foreground app - when I press it, LoL thinks I'm trying to close the game.

How can I set self casting for the Q skill with <kbd>cmd</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you obviously have to do is disabling the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> command. Otherwise you will close the application every time you want to smartcast your Q.

[The official forums have a guide on how to disable it on OSX](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=107600). The good thing with this method: you will still be able to use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> in all your other applications if you wish so.

Now for changing the Key Bindings: I'd suggest you do it in-game with the normal keybindings menu. otherwise you can find a file called `input.ini` in `Contents/LOL/Config`. There you can change the keybindings by assigning different values to the variables.

[Here you can find the default values and examples](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hotkeys_and_commands#File_Location_for_Keybindings) for the `input.ini` file.